# using regexreplace in sheets to join elements with a comma

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I want to join with a comma several words than can be found in a cell by joining them with a comma.

For example, from a cell that contains :

```
i want to use sheets to create events in calendar through gmail.
```

I want this output :
sheets, gmail, calendar

I tried a regexreplace like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(A2:A);"(.)?(sheets|calendar|gmail)?";"$2, "))))"
```

But I get various results like this :
, , , , sheets, , , , , , , , , , calendar, , , , , , , ,
, , , sheets, , , , , gmail, , , , ,
, , , , , , , gmail, , , calendar, , , , , , , , , , ,

I would like to know how to clean it like this:
sheets, calendar
sheets, gmail
gmail, calendar

to get rid of the useless commas before in between and after
so far, using a more complex formula, i can get this :

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(MINUSCULE(A2:A);"(.)?(sheets|calendar|gmail)";"$2, ");"(, )+";", ")))
```

Still, the result is not perfect, since i get this :
, sheets, calendar,
, sheets, gmail,
, gmail, calendar,

And I am using twice the regexreplace formula.
By the way, i could do it using join, or textjoin, but it is not working with arrayformula for a whole column, so it would not be appropriate.

I think this is possible using () to capture elements, but I know some are real experts when it comes to this regex!

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "(?si)(sheets|calendar|gmail)?.?", "$1 ")), "\s+", ","))
```

**NOTES**:

- `REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "(?si)(sheets|calendar|gmail)?.?", "$1 ")` - this will replace each char that is not a starting point of `sheets`, `calendar` and `gmail` substrings with a space, and will put back these char sequences if they are found
- `TRIM(...)` will strip leading/trailing whitespace from the result of the above `REGEXREPLACE`
- `REGEXREPLACE(..., "\s+", ",")` will replace chunks of 1+ whitespace chars with a single comma.

Comment: That's is really great! Thank you very much for these explanations!

By the way, is there a way to correct some wordings, for example in case of someone writes "sheet", I want to return "sheets", if "doc", then "docs":

=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "(?si)(sheets?|calendar|gmail|docs?)?.?", "$1 ")), "\s+", ","))
I remember the use of word groupings with () and $# but I am still struggling with their use. Maybe an additionnal step would be needed...

Comment: @FGS You will need another step because RE2 regex library does not support conditional replacement patterns. Besides, there is no `s` inside `doc` string, so we can't even get any workaround  to work here.